# Scraping with python with Login and bypassing Cloudfare

Tags: python, parsing, session

I'm trying to parse a website by bypassing Cloudfare using `cfscrape` and logging in afterwards.

I just started using python so I don't understand how the libraries work. Is there a way I can combine them together?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from requests import session
import cfscrape

payload = {
    'username': 'myUsername',
    'password': 'myPassword'
}

with session() as scraper:

    scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()
    scraper.post('http://kissanime.to/Login', data=payload)
    page = scraper.get('http://kissanime.to')
    page_tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    check_login = page_tree.xpath('//a[@id="aDropDown"]/span/text()')
    not_logged_in = page_tree.xpath('//a[@href="http://kissanime.to/Login"]/text()')

    print check_login
    print not_logged_in
```

`check_login` is supposed to return `myUsername` if I successfully login.